# I want to make a python script which can the switch the user and delete log file

Tags: linux, python-2.7, shell, scripting

```
sudo -iu <account name>
rm -rf filename
```

I want to make a python script that could do the above.
I tried, butas soon as I change the account, the program stops.

```
temp_dict = {'user1':['file1','file2','file3'],
             'user2':['file1','file2','file3']}
for i in temp_dict.keys():
    cmd = "sudo -iu "+user+"\n"
    for j in temp_dict[i]:
        cmd +="rm -rf "+j+"\n"
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stderr = STDOUT.PIPE)
```

The code should do something like this

```
sudo -iu user1
rm -rf file1
rm -rf file2
rm -rf file3

sudo -iu user2
rm -rf file1
rm -rf file2
rm -rf file3
```

Comment: Where is the code that yku tried?

Comment: Why do you want to use a Python script for this? It looks like two shell commands. You could write a shell script. That's probably much easier.

Comment: i need to clear logs so the files are logs and change user(owner) and delete them

Comment: **1** `-r` option for files is useles, only use for directories.  **2** this will only work if you configured your `sudo` to use `NOPASSWD`.  **3** your code produces CMD == `sudo -iu user\nrm -rf file1\n`.  This is not a valid shell command.  Your script is not a real user, it will not run commands in sequence as if you were typing them.  Look at how to run commands with sudo.  **4** if you build a script that deletes the files only,  you can then call *that* script with `sudo`.  **5** a `bash` script would do that much easier.  The right tool for the right job.

Comment: Hi @Nic3500 i will try bash but would it be able to switch users on the go I have set it sudo to use to nopasswd

Comment: Lets say you have user1, file1 and user2, file2.  You script becomes: `sudo -u user1 rm -f file1; sudo -u user2 rm -f file2`.  You then can add loop logic to process many files, list them in an array and loop on it, ...  Your sudoers must use NOPASSWD so you do not have to type passwords as these sudo commands are called.

Comment: Right now the problem I face is I can switch the user successfully but since the script was running on different user so it unable to delete the files @nic3500 after switching to the other user the program just stops